# Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function for Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-cookie, typeerror

I noticed that my jQuery dialog box no longer saves a cookie and continues to pop up each page reload. I'm not sure what changed as this was working great for nearly 1 year. I grabbed a fresh copy of jQuery UI and js Cookie but I can't figure out why I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function.

Does something need to be updated in my jQuery?

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        if( document.cookie.indexOf( "shipping_note" ) < 0 ) {
            $( ".shipping-note-container" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                show: 'slide',
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        $.cookie('shipping_note', 'Ok', { path: '/', expires: 7 });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: What is `jquery.cookie`? Did you intend to write `$.cookie` or `jQuery.cookie`?

Comment: Did you include plain jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my original post which I've corrected. It's $.cookie, not jquery.cookie. I was trying jquery.cookie as a test which didn't work. I am including plain jQuery in the head, via wp_enqueue_script('jquery') which uses http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the js [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library the methods are:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
Cookies.get('name');
.....
```

Instead if you want to use the [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) you need to download it locally and then you can use it as:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

Comment: Bingo! I'm not sure why it was failing all of a sudden but downloading a fresh copy and uploading to the server worked perfectly. Thanks so much for the help!